# MFC Em-dash and En-dash in CJK resource files

Tags: unicode, mfc, cjk, codepages, resource-file

I have a MFC application that has translation to several languages, and I want to use the characters:

- em-dash (—; Windows: Alt+0151; Unicode:\u2014)
- en-dash (–; Windows: Alt+0150; Unicode:\u2013)

For the following languages, all go well:

```
en_GB.rc: #pragma code_page(1252)
pt_PT.rc: #pragma code_page(1252)
```

but it fails for those:

```
ja-JP.rc: #pragma code_page(932) 
ko-KR.rc: #pragma code_page(949)
zh_CHS.rc: #pragma code_page(936)
```

I see strange characters. And, in situations when the string has only the dash character, is doesn't even compile in CJK languages.

Yes, I know it is possible to create strings with those characters with code like

```
CString s= _T("\u2014");
```

but that destroys the purpose of having separate resource files and it is not convenient when the dashes are inside the middle of the texts.

And, if I do something like replacing

```
IDS_HELLO_SHE_SAID_HOW_ARE_YOU " — Hello! — she said — How are you?"
```

with

```
IDS_HELLO_SHE_SAID_HOW_ARE_YOU " \u2014 Hello! \u2014 she said \u2014 How are you?"
```

I will see that \u2014 as it is (verbatim) in the interface, even in the languages that were supporting well the dash characters.
So, the question is: is there a way that I can directly put em-dashes and en-dashes in the .rc files that use those Chinese, Japanese and Korean codepages?

Thanks in advance,
Sérgio

Comment: The first question is of course why would you use codepages? Can't you save everything in Unicode?

Comment: Save the .rc files in UTF-8 and use `#pragma codepage(utf-8)`.